# Reading a long double into R

Tags: r, long-double

Is it not possible to read a `long double` from a text file into R? I've looked at the packages like `bit64`, `gmp`, `float` and others but they all seem to manage large doubles internally.

Note, I am not referring to a display ("`options(digits=22)`") problem.. I would like to read a number like `0.0664104763418435999999638041924043818653444759547710418701171875` and perform operations on it. If I'm unable to confirm I've read the full number into the session by printing it, I should be able to load and save it to a file without loss of precision. Possible not possible?

Running Fedora 29 on a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read in as character. `read.table` has the parameter `colClasses` to ensure what type the data gets interpreted to. Then you can convert to whatever multiple precision class you want. For example with `Rmpfr`:

```
library(Rmpfr)
x <- "0.0664104763418435999999638041924043818653444759547710418701171875"
mpfr(x)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  216   bits 
[1] 0.0664104763418435999999638041924043818653444759547710418701171875

# long double has 80 precision bits
mpfr(x,80)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  80   bits 
[1] 0.0664104763418435999999638
```